# connect mysql client container to mysql server container Docker

Tags: docker

I have two container

First one has mysql server

Docker file for mysql server

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server

RUN service mysql start &&  \
    sleep 5s && \
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'root'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" 

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]
```

Second container for mysql-client

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client
```

Now I run first container

```
docker run -t -i --name mysql 945bd6cace51
```

Now second container

```
docker run -t -i --link mysql:mysqla 5e6d401ee4c8
```

Use --link to connect mysql client container to mysql server container

Now in mysql client container I am using this command

mysql -h $MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR

But it is not working it shows me this error

> mysql: option '-h' requires an argument

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$MYSQLA_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR` or just `mysql -h mysqla`?

Comment: Check out docker compose -- it's designed for exactly this type of thing https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: I took reference from this article http://www.alexecollins.com/docker-linking-containers/ and I have verified from docker's website that MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR Env is for host. or whe i tried with this command mysql -h mysqla it shows me this error can't connect to mysql server on 'mysqla' (111)

Comment: Thanks engineer dollery, I will definitly give it a try But I wonder what am I doing wrong in above approach.

Comment: Not to answer, but why do you recode the wheel? https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: `MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR` should be if you use `--link mysql:mysql`, not `--link mysql:mysqla`.

Comment: @AkashJain is it possible for you to use the official MySQL client and server images from the mysql website? I also followed the exact same steps you been carrying out and ended up with the same results. Please do let me know if it works with official MySQL images? (which worked fine with me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good if you use docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8011:80"
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ../docker/apache2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
      - ../docker/apache2/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
      - ../docker/db:/root/
    container_name: web

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=root
    volumes:
      - ../docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

here we have `links:` key to use to connect mysql server to any other container.